# Congratulation to Majenko for reaching 100k reputation points

Tags: discussion, reputation, users

Congratulation to Majenko to be the first Arduino SE member reaching 100k reputation points. These points were collected on his 3,819 answers in 7 years and 5 months.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's impressive! Well done, Majenko.

Answer (score 1):

Well done Majenko!!!

The whole community thanks you for your contributions over the past 7+ years. We are wiser because of your contributions.

Thank you!